# Resizing thumbnails in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to save thumbnails in ffmpeg but for some reason I can't seem to resize them. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? THanks

```
 ffmpeg  -i input.mp4  -vf "select=gt(scene\,0.4)" -vsync  vfr scale=320:240 out%02d.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
ffmpeg  -i input.mp4  -vf "select=gt(scene\,0.4),scale=140:-1" -vsync  vfr new%02d.jpg
```